# How to handle an option change in a custom JQuery widget?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I created a widget using JQuery factory. It has an option. The option can be changed after creation of the widget.

How can I handle option change? Is there any events or methods for this?

I want something like this:

```
$.widget("myWidget", {
    options: {
        myOption: 'defaultValue'
    },

    _create: function() {
       this.initWidget(); 
    }

    initWidget: function() {
      //do initialization
    }

    _onOptionChange: function() {
       this.initWidget(); 
    }

}
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'option change'? As in, someone changing the value of a `select` element?

Comment: I mean if someone call $("#myWidget").myWidget("option", "myOption", "newValue");

Comment: Overriding _setOption and _setOptions methods solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I found is to override methods _setOption and _setOptions.

```
_setOptions: function( options ) {
    var key;
    for ( key in options ) {
    this._setOption( key, options[ key ] );
    }
    return this;
},

_setOption: function( key, value ) {
    if (key === "myOption") {
        this.initWidget();
    }    
}
```